# zoom independent scale - popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, popupwindow

I have a site being developed for the mobile browser platform. Each page is large in width and height, and requires pop-up messages to be displayed. These ideally should be accomplished by using a html pop-up.

Using a basic javascript alert/confirm will cause the browser to display a message at a size which is consistent whatever the zoom level. I.e. it doesn't get smaller when you zoom out.

Is there a way to do this with html/css

I have tried position: fixed and transform: scale().

Fixed works nicely - most of the time - but only ensures that the modal background fills the viewport
Transform: scale requires a fixed scaling value? This could be modified by javascript I suppose?

The html meta viewport tag sets up the default browser viewport level. I want the users to be able to zoom/pan around to their hearts content.

I hope I have described my problem sufficiently, however if more clarification is required let me know.

Apologies if this question has been posted somewhere else.

The only way I can think of doing this at present is to write html into a new window, however it doesn't provide the functionality I was hoping for.